# Python: BeautifulSoup returning garbage

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am building a basic data crawler in python using BeautifulSoup, for Batoto, the manga host. For some the reason, the URL works sometimes and other times it doesn't. For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen

x= urlopen(*manga url here*)
y = BeautifulSoup(x)

print y
```

The result should be a tag soup of the page but instead I get a big wall of this

```
´ºŸ{›æP™oRhtüs2å÷%ëmßñ6Y›þ�GDŸ0ËÂ­Í‡ì¼®Yé)–ÀØÅð&amp;ô]½f³ÓÞ€Þþ)ú$÷á�üv…úzW¿¾úà†lªÀí¥ï«·_    OTL_ˆêsÁÿƒÁÖ&lt;Ø?°Þ›Â+WLç¥àEh&gt;rýÜ&gt;x    ˆ‡eÇžù»èå»–Ùý e:›§`L_.‹¦úoÓ‘®e=‰ìÓ4Wëo’]~Ãõ¬À8&gt;x:²âœ2¸ Á|&amp;0ÍVpMLÎñ»v¥Ín÷-ÅÃ‰–T§`Ì.SÔsóë„œ¡×[˜·P6»�ùè�&gt;Ô¾È]Œ—·ú£âÊgí%Ø¶kwýÃ=ÜÏ¸2cïÑfÙ_�×]Õê“ž?„UÖ* m³/­`ñ§ÿL0³dµ·jªÅ}õ/õOXß×;«]®’Ï¯w‹·þ¡ÿ|Gýª`I{µœ}œí�ë–¼yÖÇ'�Wç�ëµÅþþ*ýœd{ÿDv:Ð íHzqÿÆ­÷æélG-èÈâpÇßQé´^ÐO´®Xÿ�ýö(‹šëñþ"4!SÃõ2{òÿÜ´»ûE</kî?x´&ý˜`Ù)uÂï¹ã[ÏŠ²yÂ°kÆpù}¢></uŒ¸kpž¼cìâˆ¬ƒcubÆ¡¢=en2‚påÓb9®`áï|z…p"i6pvif¨þõ“âŸ’></t`$ò-e></cé”r)$�ˆ)ìªÜrd&mÉÊ*ßdÒuÄ.Æ-hx@9[s=m�Ýfd2o1ˆ]‡[Ôádœtë¤qâxæ°‹qËÁ×,½ŠmÊ‡ê‡¢ùÅýl></sí°çù¡h?‡ÌÜœbá‰æÆý¡sd~¬></zz¡ózwÎ[à!n‰Àš5¤…¸‘Ý¹Ž></sÃ:›3Ìæ></lÑggu�».Ð‘@4õë\ÃñÆ:¸5ÔwÛ·…)~ÛacÑ,d­³båÖ6></tg9y+wÎ‰í%r8ƒ·}n`¼ÁÆ8˜”é²êÞ½°¶Ï></sÖ-di¨a±j9³4></ss„*w(ßibðïj*¶„)pâýÌ”a§%va{‰ò¦m mi></o³o˜Ÿ?¿Ñu-}{cÜ›a~:k²Ì></r+=ÅÌk˜c></wÓ¹âßŠž‡ëf7vÑ�akÆ4ƒ‚></szŽµiÞêzâšÒ¬ú¢“âÀ#�-></qebndÎ‘g*cxgsÆ€Ùüe¡³-ŠngÁ:�3ænæ5ï0`coäÏÖ9œ1Ða¯,æ—ªìàãÉÂð></j›h¶`à;)òiÖ š+></o”64ˆÎº9°��u—Úd¿ý¥pÎÖ‰0¢s:c�yÆ§³t=ÕŸ“Ý‹41%}*,e³Ô¥ó></hiræe—';></v�fÞ«Ë¥n§Ð·¡kaììë\�`ùsõ©¸pv¦‘></bñ¼ut«w)Ø'¹ú@{)n0¡Žan¶Ë5èsª�–u–></y_x.mÅd:g}ëÕðhçðÂ«õõ8ŠcËÕÌvž­v™-šêÙ`b¹˜ùÃÎ“çË¤ÔÙtx¹�ßïÇ¶Îgþ°r‹$ò†aÆ–š?ì<y«Ëñõo{%×‡o{ú¥Á»æ]‡></u´¬Ø¸eÖïÝtßÚ'è3®nh±ûk4È@l«s]–Åec¹ÑtmÓl|ë£Þ¼~zôéõûwêÓÑñÉÆw\soøÊiyjvØÖ$¯ÈoºÙoyã]æ5]-t^[“¡aÑ{²Å¸6¦ðtŒçm¼ÂÎz´></wà™´»äõ@©õ></mÏu:=¼þ·'�qwúËö«m„l^ˆær¥30q±ÒšŸëù></lî™¯(„7¼=xi’?¤;ö$ØË4ßoóiòyoµxÉøþ¨—«g³Ãíß{|></body></html>
```

wrapped in html and body tags.

Sometimes I will keep trying and it works, but it is so inconsistent, I can't figure out the reason for it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `x= requests.get` will work, it looks like urlopen ia having problems with encoding

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I agree, pretty sure `requests` would handle it automagically.

Comment: @alecxe, yep I just tried, works fine every time

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I think you can post it as an answer. At least one upvote guaranteed :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to be urlopen having issues with encoding, [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) works fine:

```
x = requests.get("http://bato.to/comic/_/comics/rakudai-kishi-no-eiyuutan-r11615")
y = BeautifulSoup(x.content)    
print y


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Rakudai Kishi no Eiyuutan - Scanlations - Comic - Comic Directory - Batoto -    Batoto</title>
.................
```

Using urlopen we get the following:

```
x = urlopen("http://bato.to/comic/_/comics/rakudai-kishi-no-eiyuutan-r11615")    
print x.read()


���������s+I���2���l��9C<�� ^�����쾯�dw�xzNT%��,T��A^�ݫ���9��a��E�C���W!�����ڡϳ��f7���s2�Px$���}I�*�'��;'3O>���'g?�u®{����e.�ڇ�e{�u���jf:aث
�����DS��%��X�Zͮ���������9�:�Dx�����\-�
�*tBW������t�I���GQ�=�c��\:����u���S�V(�><y�C��ã�*:�ۜ?D��a�g�o�sPD�m�"�,�Ɲ<;v[��s���=��V2�fX��ì�Cj̇�В~�
-~����+;V���m�|kv���:V!�hP��D�K�/`oԣ|�k�5���B�{�0�wa�-���iS
�>�œ��gǿ�o�OE3jçCV<`���Q!��5�B��N��Ynd����?~��q���� _G����;T�S'�@΀��t��Ha�.;J�61'`Й�@���>>`��Z�ˠ�x�@� J*u��'���-����]p�9{>����������#�<-~�K"[AQh0HjP
0^��R�]�{N@��
 ...................
```

So as you can see it is a problem with `urlopen` not `BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: Thank you. Requests is a great library

Comment: @user3758912, you're welcome, I agree it is a great and easy to use library.

Answer (score 1):

The server is returning gzipped bytes. So to download the content using `urllib2`:

```
import sys
import urllib2
import gzip
import io
url = "http://bato.to/comic/_/comics/rakudai-kishi-no-eiyuutan-r11615"
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)

# print(response.headers)
content = response.read()
if response.headers['Content-Encoding'] == 'gzip':
    g = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=io.BytesIO(content))
    content = g.read()

encoding = response.info().getparam('charset')
content = content.decode(encoding)
```

This checks the content is the same as the `page.text` returned by `requests`:

```
import requests
page = requests.get(url)
# print(page.headers)

assert content == page.text
```

Since `requests` handles the gunzipping and decoding for you -- and more robustly too -- using `requests` is highly recommended.